# Get related data in contain request

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

Consider these (CakePHP3) models and their relations:

**Menus**

```
name | user_id
```

**Menutimetables**

```
herd_id | menu_id | start | end
```

> Menus hasMany Menutimetables
>
> Menutimetables belongsTo Menus
>
> Menutimetables belongsTo Herds
>
> Herds hasMany Menutimetables

In my controller I'm getting all data with

```
$herd = $this->Herds->get($id, [
    'contain' => [
        'Menutimetables' => ['sort' => ['start'=>'asc']]
    ]
]);
```

Which results in getting the menu_id.

```
menu_id   start   end
8         1       5
9         6       9
6         10      15
```

Where in fact I want to see the `Menus.name`.

How can I get that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try:**

```
$herd = $this->Herds->get($id, [
    'contain' => [
        'Menutimetables.Menus'
        'Menutimetables' => ['sort' => ['start'=>'asc']]
    ]
]);
```

Comment: Awsome, works like a charm. In order to get the value I've used `$menutimetables->menu->name`. In case anyone else runs into the same problem.